# simultaneously sending/receiving info from a server, in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to figure out how to make a server that can accept multiple clients at one time. While doing so, I need the client able to send and receive data from the server at the same time.

Would i have to make a threaded server? And have a thread for listening for data.

And then another thread for sending out information to the client?

Then for the client side, do i need use threads to send/get info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use async IO. There are dozen of async IO socket libs for python. [Here](http://nichol.as/asynchronous-servers-in-python) is a brief benchmark.
I also tested `gevent`, `eventlet`, `asyncore`, `twisted`, `pyev`, `pycurl`, `tornado`.

- **Twsited**
  is stable but most slow and also not easy to start with.
- **gevent, eventlet (libevent)**
  easy to start and fast (code looks like blocking) but have some issues with forking.
- **pycurl (libcurl)**
  fast and easy (if you ok to do flags magic.. but there are example) but only http.
- **pyev (libev)**
  you must understand what you are doing almost like polling yourself.
- **tornado (polling in python)**
  fast enough and i think stable and also easy to start.
- **asyncore**
  really fast.. but don't use it.. it is ugly-ugly.

Don't use threads in python unless you are really know what you are doing.
Python and threads not really big friends (unless version <3.2 in 3.2 there must be a new gil).

Answer (score 2):

On server-side you clearly need a [Socket Server](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socketserver.html?highlight=tcpserver). This server creates a new thread for every incoming client connection.

Once a connection is established, both the client and the thread that was instantiated for the communication require an additional thread if they have to do other business in parallel than listening to the socket if the communication is synchronous. In case an asynchronous communication is what you need, then Python provides an excellent [Asynchronous Socket Handler](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/asyncore.html).

Comment: So would threads not be needed then on a asynchronous server?

Comment: It is absolutely needed. It can, however, be encapsulated in a library or framework, like Socket Server, so that you do not need to work the the thread objects directly.

Comment: would i import Socket Server into asynchronous? And then, what would i use from the Socket Server?

Answer (score 1):

Use a asynchronous socket. Example server could be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-echo-server) and the client code [here](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-http-client). No direct hassle with threads. Depending on your needs, you probably don't need the asynchronous client.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need threads for either client or server; you can instead select() to multiplex all the I/O inside a single thread.